creating drop-down lists or toggle-switch buttons in a treeview with tkinter in Python
enter image description hereI try to  create a menu like this in tkinter. Here is what I would like on this picture. In this Menu, I have categories (here on the picture for example General Options, Body Options, Neck Options...). When I click on a categories, a sub-list of others options appear (for example for the Neck Options, we can see Neck Wood, Number of frets, Neck Profile etc.). And if I click on one option, I want to selection one option (it could be a drop-down list or a toggle switch or checkbox, whatever allowing to choose something). For example here, in the option Fingerboard Radius, I can choose 14, 12, 10, 12-16.
I tried to embed toggle-switch and drop-down list in a treeview but it doesn't seem it is possible... I tried using tab but no, it is not what I want.
Here is an example using drop-down-list :
import tkinter as tk

class GuitareDesignerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Guitare Designer")

        # Frame à gauche
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=200, bg="gray")
        self.left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)

        # Frame central
        self.center_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        self.center_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        # Frame à droite
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=200, bg="gray")
        self.right_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)

        # Catégories avec options
        self.categories = {
            "Options générales": ["Dextérité", "Marque"],
            "Body": ["Type de bois", "Forme"],
            "Neck": ["Type de bois", "Type de manche"],
            "Head": ["Type de tête", "Logo"],
            "Electronics": ["Micros", "Système électronique"],
            "Hardware": ["Chevalet", "Mécaniques"],
            "Export/Load": ["Exporter", "Charger"]
        }

        # Label pour les catégories
        self.category_labels = []
        for category in self.categories:
            label = tk.Label(self.left_frame, text=category, bg="gray", fg="white")
            label.pack(fill="x", pady=5)
            self.category_labels.append(label)

        # Menu déroulant pour les options
        self.option_menus = {}
        for category, options in self.categories.items():
            option_var = tk.StringVar(self.left_frame)
            option_var.set(options[0])  # Initialisation avec la première option
            menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.left_frame, option_var, *options)
            menu.pack(fill="x", padx=10)
            self.option_menus[category] = option_var

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GuitareDesignerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

and here another on with treeview :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Application")

        # Création de l'arbre
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
        self.tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.on_select)

        # Ajout des éléments à l'arbre
        general_node = self.tree.insert("", "end", text="général")
        body_node = self.tree.insert("", "end", text="body")

        self.tree.insert(general_node, "end", text="dextérité")
        self.tree.insert(general_node, "end", text="marque")

        self.tree.insert(body_node, "end", text="bois")
        self.tree.insert(body_node, "end", text="couleur")

        # Panneau droit
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", width=200)
        self.right_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.color_label = ttk.Label(self.right_frame, text="Couleur:")
        self.color_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.color_combo = ttk.Combobox(self.right_frame, values=["Noir", "Blanc", "Sunburst"])
        self.color_combo.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def on_select(self, event):
        selected_item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        selected_text = self.tree.item(selected_item, "text")

        if selected_text == "couleur":
            self.color_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.color_combo.grid(row=2, column=1)
        else:
            self.color_label.grid_forget()
            self.color_combo.grid_forget()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


What have you tried so far?

I tried to embed toggle-switch and drop-down list in a treeview but it doesn't seem it is possible...
Apparently I can't paste my differents  scripts because we are limited in characters. But I wrote scripts with the treeview widget, and tried to put in the treeview the buttons, but it doens't work. I read apparently function tkinter can't embed other functions. I also try to use drop-down list to put a drop-down list inside another drop-down list, but obviously it doensn't work at all...

I mean to say, please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. We can't work on code we can't see, so it's always recommended to put relevant code in the body of your question.

OK, I put 2 examples in the main question ;).
